# How to parse an HTML node's attributes

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

I use C# and need to parse an HTML to read the attributes into key value pairs.
e.g given the following HTML snippet

```
<DIV myAttribute style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-TOP: medium none" id=my_ID anotherAttribNamedDIV class="someclass">
```

Please note that the attributes can be
1. key="value" pairs e.g `class="someclass"`
2. key=value pairs e.g `id=my_ID` (no quotes for values)
3. plain attributes e.g `myAttribute`, which doesn't have a "value"

I need to store them into a dictionary with key value pairs as follows
`key=myAttribute value=""`
`key=style value="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-TOP: medium none"`
`key=id value="my_ID"`
`key=anotherAttribNamedDIV value=""`
`key=class value="someclass"`

I am looking for regular expressions to do this.

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Don't use capitals for your html tags.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

```
string myDiv = @"<DIV myAttribute style=""BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-TOP: medium none"" id=my_ID anotherAttribNamedDIV class=""someclass""></DIV>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(myDiv);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div");

Literal1.Text = ""; 

foreach (HtmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
{
    Literal1.Text += attr.Name + ": " + attr.Value + "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation (and formatting for the code)?